# How to make 2D scatter plot in Matlab with colors depending on values?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have three vectors of the same lenght: `x`, `y`, and `cls`. I want to make a 2D plot of x and y but each point should have a color corresponding to the value of `cls`.

I thought about using the `scatter` function but you can chage the color of the whole plot, not of particular elements. Any ideas?

I would like to get something like in this example, when `cls` has elements of three values:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help of scatter:

scatter(x,y,a,c) specifies the circle colors. To plot all circles with the same color, specify c as a single color string or an RGB triplet. To use varying color, specify c as a vector or a three-column matrix of RGB triplets.

you can construct c as

```
c=zeros(size(x),3);
c(cls==1,:)=[1 0 0]; % 1 is red
% ...
scatter(x,y,1,c)
```

However, I dont know how to do the background. Did you apply some Machine learning algorithm to clasify the data? maybe you can get the equations to plot the background from there, but it depends on the method.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, there is an easy way of doing this, it's called `gscatter`.

It takes similar inputs to `scatter`, but the third input is the group:

```
gscatter(x,y,cls)
```

You can add colours and markers - this plots with red, then green, then blue (order determined by the contents of `cls`, all markers circles.

```
gscatter(x,y,cls,'rgb','o')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution splitting your data in three using logical indexing:

```
% Some random data
x = rand(100,1);
y = rand(100,1);
cls = round(2*rand(100,1));

% Split the data in three groups depending on the value in cls
x_red = x(cls==0);
y_red = y(cls==0);
x_green = x(cls==1);
y_green = y(cls==1);
x_blue = x(cls==2);
y_blue = y(cls==2);

% plot the data
scatter(x_red,y_red,1,'r')
hold on
scatter(x_green,y_green,1,'g')
scatter(x_blue,y_blue,1,'b')
hold off
```

Comment: if you go through the effort of splitting your data yourself, and you don't use the additional functionalities of `scatter` (e.g. different color/size per point), you could simply plot each of your group with a `line` object (_with_ `'Linestyle','none','Marker','o'`). The performance will be improved if you have a large number of point.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution with `c` being the color vector:

```
scatter3(X,Y,zeros(size(X,1)),4,c);    
view(0,90);
```