# How to plot a magnitudes of a value in a vector against latitude and longitude in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a list of velocities collected along a ship track. I would like to plot the magnitudes of the velocities against the latitude and longitude coordinates of the point at which the data was collected? Any ideas on how to plot this? Something like pcolor wouldn't work because the velocities data is only a vector. Thank you.

Comment: You could use Matlab's [`scatter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) function.

Comment: That's a smart idea man. Thank you. But I would want to show the variations in magnitude with color not the circle size. Any idea on an easy way to generate a color matrix that would represent the magnitudes in my values. For example - 0 - 10 cm/s, 10-20 cm/s ...etc would have a specific color value for each range.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754626/how-to-make-2d-scatter-plot-in-matlab-with-colors-depending-on-values. I googled "matlab scatter color by value" (last two words suggested by Google) and it was the 4th hit (1st from SO).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make 2D scatter plot in Matlab with colors depending on values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754626/how-to-make-2d-scatter-plot-in-matlab-with-colors-depending-on-values)

Comment: @Darkgod The `scatter` function does exactly that. Check out the example in that doc page. You can fix the circle sizes for all data points and change their color based on the z values.